# Como posso fazer uma autenticação oauth2 de um aplicativo android nativo com um site desenvolvido com wordpress?

Tags: java, android, wordpress, oauth2

Eu tenho um site desenvolvido com wordpress, e não na plataforma wordpress.com .

Ultimamente venho fazendo testes para utilizar restfull e consumir os dados via json pelo aplicativo android nativo.

Só que gostaria de poder autenticar de uma forma segura utilizando oauth2 com chave expirando. Fui atrás de um plugin e encontrei 
https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/
inclusive com a versão paga. acontece que não consigo fazer a autenticação oauth2 do lado do cliente no aplicativo android.

Como faço essa authentição oauth2 direto com meu site em wordpress, da mesma forma que podemos fazer utilizando uma api com o google, facebook, instagran e outros ??

Seguindo a documentação eu instalei Postman para o navegador, onde eu posso ver/testar o que estou enviando e recebendo do servidor.

Configurei o plugin como

Authorization Code: () HTTP redirects and WP login form when authenticating.
Client Credentials: () Enable "Client Credentials" Grant Type
User Credentials: (x) Enable "User Credentials" Grant Type
Refresh Tokens: (x) Enable "Refresh Token" Grant Type
Allow Implicit: () Enable "Authorization Code (Implicit)" What is this?

e utilizando o postman  configurei 
post www.bancodepeticoes.com?oauth=token

e os campos 
grant_type    password
username      usuariodowordpress
password      senhadowordpress

enable x-www-form-undercoled

apos recebo

{
  "access_token": "7jaux9vehfjmvshfbxubtcqouz1kdv",

"expires_in": 3600,

"token_type": "Bearer",

"scope": "basic",

"refresh_token": "nru6pmkpl5clbavwzk0senihtav7mp"

}

agora como preencher/requerer nova novo acesso token com essas informações.

nos campos

Token Name:         -
Auth URL:           -
Access Token URL:       -
cliente id :            -
Cliente secret          -
Scope (Opcional)
Grand type     (Client credentials / Autorization code)

Consegui a autenticacao basica e acho que depois devo subir esse acesso para oauth2 uma vez que nao tenho todos esses dados antes. logando primeiro somente com o nome de usuario e senha.

recebo o erro

cloud not send request...

cloud not complete Auth2.0 login ...

É possivel utilizar a api oauth2 do google para isso ?

## também tentei acessar

http://www.site.com/GET/posts/2233/revision?Access_token=0ntd3uvec3dgarrh667a0ryyv5qoyb

utilizando o token gerado e não funcionou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não consigo renovação de token com este formulario.
que url deve inserir nos campos de auth url e access token url ????

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente o plugin disponibiliza um servidor de oauth. A versão do link que você postou parece antiga. Mas, qual o erro? O que você tentou? fazer?

Comment: acredito que ele transforma a própria instalação do wordpress em um servidor oauth. tendo autenticação basica  criando um cliente e usando seu id e secret... seguindo a documentação do mesmo utilizando um plugin do navegador onde posso ir testando as url... para fazer a autenticação básica funciona, porém quando tento com as credenciais do usuario do wordpress, não consigo e não encontro em lugar nenhum  como fazer isso.